# How can i login to linkedin using HTTP POST Request with C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, post, fiddler

I am working on a simple Windows Forms program that take a username and password from a "Textbox" then it show my linked-in name in a "Messagebox".

I want to accomplish the code with the using of "HttpWebRequest" or using any method to send my POST request to Linked-in then i can get the response and find my name to shown it in a "Messagebox".

I am familiar with creating a "GET" Request and also i made some "POST" Requests but in this case i didn't know how can i send my "txt_UserName.Text" and "txt_Password" with the POST Request and how can i receives the Response.

I tried to using Fiddler to capture POST request (=POST) from linkedin when i try to login but it captures more than 4 requests when i see the header of them it seem like a GET Request this is an example of one:

```
GET /nhome/?trk= HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

and all of them have a multiple cookies values.

This is my POST request code:

```
    public void SubmitData()
    {
        try
        {              
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.linkedin.com");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            //Content Length
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());

            sr.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now the only thing i wish to know, how can i send my username and password as a values to login to linked-in?

---

Edit:

Below is my second try, it's ok, i can now send the User and Password in postData and i can store the Cookies and retrive it. but there are two issues:
1- how can i make sure that the login is accomplished and not failed
2- if the login is accomplished i want to know what is the second step to get my name from profile, is it made another request or what ?

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PostMessage();
    }


    private void PostMessage()
    {
        try { 

        // POST Data and the POST uri
        string    postData = "isJsEnabled=true&source_app=&session_key=" + textBox1.Text + "&session_password=" + textBox2.Text + "&signin=Sign+In&session_redirect=";
        string    uri = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit";

        // Encoding the POST Data
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        // Create the POST Request
        HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        //POST Parameters (Method and etc.)
        WebReq.Method = "POST";
        WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        WebReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        // Set the POST Request Cookies
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        WebReq.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();


        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        //MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
        sr.Close();
        dataStream.Close();

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Error: " + response.StatusDescription);
            response.Close();
        }

        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cook.Name + " " + cook.Value);
        }

            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("POST Message Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you read the LinkedIn documentation at https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin ?

Comment: The sign in with linked in button is an authentication mechanism, best to use the APIs to get the data this guy is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need more than you think to log in there is good documentation on how to do this just [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication), you are going to need an auth token etc, This is because like other services, for example google, they are using oauth2 to secure applications etc.

oauth works by issuing tokens and refreshing tokens and there's a bit of a learning curve but its not especially difficult.

Essentially the following happens

1. You register your application with linked in and they give you a
   client secret.
2. You pass this code to linked in in your application
   and they will generate an auth screen saying that the application is
   requesting permission.
3. you then approve this and it will give you an access token
4. You then log in with the access token (access tokens on linkedin are valid for 60 days, you must refresh them by this time).

On the plus side the linked in api is pretty straight forward and once authorised you will be able to get stuff pretty easily. All of this is detailed in the link provided in nice step by step stages.

By the way there is also a nuget package that gives you access to profile information.

Try `Install-Package LinkedIn`

I should point out that the nuget package above gives you a login provider to help authenticate if you don't want to roll your own.

Added after your comments below.

If all you want to do is know how to send a post request here's a generic bit of code that does just that:

```
string url = "www.foo.bar.com";

using (var webClient= new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["username"] = "<yourusername>";
    data["password"] = "<yourPassword>";

    var response = webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
}
```

note: because its a web uri you should use POST in the method argument here.

Comment: i know that i can use APIs but i think i should use the HTTP Request only without using APIs. i work on this example to know more about the HTTP Requests and responses.

Comment: Not really the way you are meant to do it I'm afraid.

Comment: I know that this way might not be a correct way, but this when i use it in illegal way. i am only write a test program. my target not linked-in but my target is how can i use HTTP Request, Response with C#

Comment: Added generic post details if this is what you want.

Comment: thank you, your answer is clear and i will try it now and replay to you again

Answer (score 0):

I used Fiddler while I was logging in and found a request to https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit containing the username and password. Found it?  Now, if you want to look at it completely from an HTTP Request perspective, you will have to figure out how to generate the other data in the post data/cookie header using the other requests and responses that your browser sent and received to and from the site before this particular request (the information should be there). I think this will lead you to what you need to do, but there's some work to be done!

Comment: thank you, i tried to find it but i can't. i will make another try and replay to you again.

Comment: ok i found the POST Request 
POST /uas/login-submit HTTP/1.1
and there are alot of cookies values but my problem is how can i know which cookie key i should use and how can i pass my textbox values (txt_User.Text and txt_Pass.Text) as a cookies values to get the response
i think i should give you a correct answer but i wish you can help me in this

Comment: Well the password string is in the PostData, so you would simply replace the POST body's appropriate fields with the username password through a string.Format perhaps (using your code). Use fiddler's WebForms tab to see the fields broken down. Right click on a request on Fiddler->Replay->Reissue from Composer and see that if you reexecute it without all required data, it won't work. It's a little bit of work to sift through that data to get the information for the request.

Comment: Anwyay if you've never actually done this before I think you should start with a much simpler site for educational purposes, maybe where you don't need cookies and where you don't require a lot of other data in the POST string.

Comment: i do what you tell me. but please can you see my last edit in the question and if you can edit your answer with code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem you up against is that Linkedin uses a redirect within the login session and is differcult to catch.
So somehow within the login session you need to code that it redirects to the https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/?trk= this provides the user page access.

I am also testing with this, however did not manage to figure this part out, normally
      httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true; 
should do the trick but not in this case it does not work.

So if you find the solution let me know, if I find will post it also.